# Is it true that $ Pr(X\leq a, Y\leq b)=1 \Leftrightarrow a=\infty, b=\infty $ for continuous random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider two random variables $X,Y$ both continuously distributed on $\mathbb{R}$. Also the random vector $(X,Y)$ is continuously distributed on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It follow that
$$
Pr(X\leq a)=1 \Leftrightarrow a=\infty
$$
and
$$
Pr(Y\leq b)=1 \Leftrightarrow b=\infty
$$

**Without imposing further assumptions on the joint distribution of $X,Y$**, can we also say that 
$$
Pr(X\leq a, Y\leq b)=1 \Leftrightarrow a=\infty, b=\infty
$$
?

---

**Edit** following suggestion in answer below: I should replace the starting sentence "*Consider two random variables $X,Y$ both continuously distributed on $\mathbb{R}$. Also the random vector $(X,Y)$ is continuously distributed on $\mathbb{R}^2$*."

with

"*Consider two random variables $X,Y$ both continuous and with non-negative density on $\mathbb{R}$. Also the random vector $(X,Y)$ is continuous with non-negative density on $\mathbb{R}^2$.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $X$ and $Y$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1].$ Then $P(X\le 2,Y\le 2) =1).$

Your assertion that it is true for single random variables is similarly wrong. Unless you are using a different definition of "continuously distributed on $\mathbb R$" than what is standard.

**edit**

In response to the clarification, yes, if $(X,Y)$ has positive density my on all of $\mathbb R^2$ then we have $P(X\le x,Y\le y) < 1$ if $x$ or $y$ are less than $\infty.$  If $y < \infty$ then we can integrate positive density over the region $X\le x, Y>y$ and get a positive probability outside the original region.

But having positive density on $\mathbb R^2$ does not follow from each variable having positive density on $\mathbb R.$ For instance we can have $X$ a standard normal and $Y=-X.$ Then both are marginally standard normal but two quadrants of $\mathbb R^2$ have zero density.

But your statement still holds in this weaker situation since if there is zero probability of that $X>x$ or $Y>y,$ then there must be zero probability that $X>x$ and zero probability that $Y>y.$

Comment: OK, I see. Which assumption would ensure that $X$ and $Y$ can take any value on $\mathbb{R}$? Is it something like "positive Lebesgue density everywhere ..."? That is what I (wrongly) meant by "continuously distributed on $\mathbb{R}$".

Comment: Maybe you want something like "has positive density on all of $\mathbb R$" (or $\mathbb R^2$)

Comment: Let me add this to my question, apologies

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. Then the answer is yes if $(X,Y)$ has positive density on all of $\mathbb R^2$ but this does not follow from $X$ and $Y$ both having positive density on all of $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify your last statemenr "But your statement still holds in this weaker situation since if there is zero probability of that $X>x$ or $Y>y$, then there must be zero probability that $X>x$ and zero probability that $Y>y$."? Are you saying that IF $X,Y$ are both continuous and with non-negative density on $\mathbb{R}$, THEN $\mathbb{P}(X\leq a, Y\leq b)=1 $ IF AND ONLY IF $a=b=\infty$?

Comment: @STF yes that's what I'm saying. Come to think of it I could have omitted the first argument entirely and just used that.